# Is "promote" equal to "advertising" or "implementing further" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I find this in [the message by UNWTO for World Tourism Day 2016](http://wtd.unwto.org/content/official-messages-world-tourism-day-0):

> We thus urge all countries and destinations, as well as the industry, to promote accessibility for all in the physical environment, in transport systems, in public facilities and services and in information and communications channels.

*Promote* is kind of ambiguous to me. What does it say? It means that there should *advertisements* in the places mentioned, say pictures expressing the importance of "accessibility for all to tourism" or it means in the places mentioned, measures must be taken so that the disabled can experience better?

Comment: See definition nos. 1 (and 4) at [Collins Dictionary.](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/promote) Is is indeed a little ambiguous, but the intended meaning is clear from the U.N. source and from the context (although advertising _could_ be used by countries et al. to promote accessibility.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure in every language there are words and phrases that people associate with "government speech" or "academic speech" or "doctor speech" or various other professions.  In this sentence, the UN doesn't say the countries should *create* more handicapped-friendly services because that sounds like they're telling people what to do -- instead they use the more passive "promote accessibility" because that sounds friendlier and less pushy, even though "create" is what they mean.

As a related example, doctors can often use more neutral and less scary words with their patients to avoid adding to their stress.  So they'll call something a "condition" instead of a "disease", or recommend the patient "pursue an aggressive course of treatment" when they mean "chemotherapy".